# Method with variable parameter values without changing its signature

Tags: java, c#

**This post is about a job interview question I had, I'm asking here to find different ways I should used to solve it.**

The interviewer asked me to write on a whiteboard how I will design a method that will receive a Person object, so I write this:

```
class Person
{
    //Some properties
}

public void MyMethod(Person p)
{   
}
```

Then the interviewer told me the method must receive a list(array) of addresses for the person, I modified like this:

```
class Person
{
    //Some properties
    private List<Address> adds;
}

class Address
{
    //Some properties
}

public void MyMethod(Person p)
{   
}
```

Then he told me the method must receive a list of persons with addresses and also a list of bosses for that person so I did this:

```
class Parameter
{
    private List<Person> pers;
}

class Person
{
    //Some properties
    private List<Address> adds;
    private List<Boss> boss;
}

class Address
{
    //Some properties
}

class Boss
{
    //Some properties
}

public void MyMethod(Parameter p)
{   
}
```

(In every change he told me the method signature must not be modified)

The interviewer just said "ok" but I did not think he was very convinced with my approach, I'm not an expert in C# or Java (the interviewer said he master Java) and I was so nervous that just came to my mind this "easy" solution, but seems it was a very bad choice.

I will appreciate if you can guide me to solve this in the best way using C# or Java

Comment: I think the interviewer expected you to have Boss extend Person, alors your method doesn't receive a list of addresses, it receives a Person which already has a list of addresses. I'm not sure what you tried to do with Parameter.

Comment: So not changing the methods signature was a requirement? You wrote that in the title but never clarified it in the question.

Comment: IMHO the `Boss` should have a list of Subordinates, not the `Person` a list of Bosses... Also a `Boss` usually is a `Person` therefore class  `Boss` should extend class `Person`.

Comment: @PaulLemarchand The parameter class was created because he asked me to receive a list of persons

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Thanks for notice it, I just modified the question to add that

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Inheritance... damn I forgot that, I think you're right :(

Comment: Maybe he wanted you to to use varargs. Like this: `public void MyMethod(Person... persons)`.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm ok I think the important thing to mention here are also different views on the behavior of the entities.

So the Address class or better it should be a DataType class which is immutable is ok. A Person can have one or more address objects.
My question would be related to the Boss and Person class: Do you want a Boss which knows N persons or do you want a Person that knows N Boss objects or both so a 1:N or N:M relation.

My advise related to the question of extending the Boss with Person is don't do this. You have simple Entity classes and extension is heavy. If you want such a behaviour use composition so e.g. the Boss has an person attribute with delegation or simple reuse your data types by defining address and so on again in the Boss class.

With the not changing parameter ok thats a little stupid. I get whats your purpose with the Parameter class but thats not a good way. So if your method should receive only a Person object use a Person type otherwise overload the method with a Collection type.

So this is only my opinion about this topic ;)